# createjs button in flash is not working

Tags: flash, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I am trying to convert flash into html5 using createJs, however, button is not getting triggered, check code by [downloading sample file here.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/b6kwax68ni3im2s/300x250_createJs.zip)

```
    this.ReplayBtn = new lib.replayBtn();
    this.ReplayBtn.onClick = function() {
      console.log("clicked");
      this.gotoAndPlay("animate");

    }
```

Here is jsFiddle link [jsfiddle.net/asimkh/sLbgrx08/1](http://jsfiddle.net/asimkh/sLbgrx08/1)

Comment: No one is going to download a sample file. Create a jsFiddle instead

Comment: here is  jsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/asimkh/sLbgrx08/1/

Comment: For Flash/CreateJS samples, an FLA is preferable to a fiddle link. It takes quite a bit of fiddling to get it working properly, especially since JSFiddle refuses to use newer versions of CreateJS in their library dropdown (the most recent is now 2 years old). As someone who answers CreateJS questions a lot, I will definitely download and test an FLA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a quick edit to fix the fiddle you posted in the previous answer's comment.
https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/sLbgrx08/20/

The `var createjs` is in a poor place in the fiddle, and was causing some issues. It would have worked locally for you, just not on jsfiddle. This "fixed" version that displays your initial issue.

---

The remaining issue is that your image is being loaded cross-domain, resulting in an error when you click. This is because EaselJS mouse interaction requires pixel access, but the cross-domain image makes the canvas "dirty", which prevents it. You can see the error in the console, and it looks like you even copied the error into the Flash timeline, so you must have seen it.

> Uncaught An error has occurred. This is most likely due to security
>   restrictions on reading canvas pixel data with local or cross-domain
>   images.

You can not really get around this using the CDN you are pointing at, since it doesn't send cross-origin headers, which are necessary. Additionally, the old version of PreloadJS does not support cross-origin well.

I made a quick revision to your code, preloading the images manually, from a source that DOES support cross-origin requests (my test domain), and got it working. It took some hacking on the CreateJS generated code to get it to preload properly, but note that newer versions of the library support this no problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/sLbgrx08/22/

Additionally, I made some changes to your frame scripts:

1. Putting core logic like stage ticking and setup in your frame_0 is not advisable. The stage updates already in the HTML file, so use that. Externalizing your JavaScript outside of the FLA is good as well.
2. I bound your click handler, like I mentioned in my earlier answer. This will ensure the function is called in the right scope:

`this.ReplayBtn.onClick = clickHandler.bind(this);`

3. The way you defined and called the `animateCall` function *might* work, but it is really specific. Since you have defined the function on that clip, just call it in that scope. The frame scripts are scoped to the clip they live in:

`this.animateCall();`

4. When you call `animateCall`, you are going to the "animate" label, which is frame 0. This causes the frame 0 script to get called again (another reason to externalize your JS from Flash). I commented out the `gotoAndPlay` for now.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` and similar events were deprecated a while back, so depending on which version of CreateJS this is targeting, they won't work. Use the EventDispatcher methods instead:

```
this.ReplayBtn = new lib.replayBtn();
this.ReplayBtn.on("click", handleClick, this);
function handleClick(event) {
  console.log("clicked");
  this.gotoAndPlay("animate");
}
```

Note that the scope of your initial code may not work as well, because JavaScript does not maintain the function scope - so `this` would be `Window`. Using the 3rd parameter of the `on()` method will solve this.

If you have an older version of CreateJS without `on()`, you can use:

```
this.ReplayBtn.addEventListener("click", handleClick.bind(this));
```

Cheers.

Comment: Looking at the code, it appears you might be using a SUPER old version of  CreateJS. Are you using Flash CC, or the Toolkit for CreateJS panel? Unfortunately JSFiddle only has the one version in their dropdown (we haven't been able to get a newer version in), and even it is a few versions newer than what you might be using.

Comment: I am using Flash CS6 using createjs toolkit to generate html5, 
its super old version since i cannot find another,
its below version, also update https://jsfiddle.net/asimkh/sLbgrx08/19/ 

easeljs-0.5.0.min.js 
tweenjs-0.3.0.min.js 
movieclip-0.5.0.min.js
preloadjs-0.2.0.min.js


i tried the above code but didn’t work still :(

Answer (score 0):

i checked your button . it will not work for main .jpg. so do not make your .jpg bitmap to movieclip. you require to recreate another rectangle of 0 opacity and name it "ReplayBtn"